# Node.js module CSURF question -- how do ANTI-CSRF tokens get computed?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I'm using the node.js module CSURF, which is configured to use cookies via cookie-parser.

For demo purposes, I'm just echoing the ANTI-CSRF token to the screen on a /form GET request. Here's the request and response via VS Code Rest Client plugin:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/form HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
cookie: sid=s%3AYdAxaIHCvv38D6vd3VOi085SOzqkuZpN.eloHBwtgNm4yXQia3FtgR6puNj48kNZVbxlWtBZhSk0; _csrf=xdfFevA7j1qcGRo5BvB7JDQ2



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Expect-CT: max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 52
ETag: W/"34-4PDt3TpquKFR5AlQtYw1wqZJRD4"
Date: Wed, 03 Nov 2021 02:47:01 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "csrfToken": "HhEOYbdx-lhbaEmFT_Udx-CyyZFvuXG2u3lI"
}
```

You can see the _csrf value in the cookie -- xdfFevA7j1qcGRo5BvB7JDQ2

Interestingly, this doesn't match the token output to screen -- HhEOYbdx-lhbaEmFT_Udx-CyyZFvuXG2u3lI

So I presume it's a cryptographic match, or a salt was added to the _csrf value to generate unique ANTI-CSRF tokens every time.

...which is fine, b/c CSURF works when I issue a POST request using HhEOYbdx-lhbaEmFT_Udx-CyyZFvuXG2u3lI.

The question/confusion comes into play when I issue a new GET request to the /form endpoint. The _csrf value (xdfFevA7j1qcGRo5BvB7JDQ2) doesn't change, only the ANTI-CSRF token that was output to the screen.

So it appears the ANTI-CSRF token changes on every request, but the cookie value doesn't. Is this correct behavior? It doesn't seem like it b/c I'd be able to always use any ANTI-CSRF token to bypass the check.

Here's the full code from CSURF URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')
 
// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
 
// create express app
var app = express()
 
// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
app.use(cookieParser())
 
app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  // changed original code to display token to screen instead of render it within a form; this is for dev purposes only
  res.json({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})
 
app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Per OWASP (see this URL: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/csrf-token-unique-per-user-session-why), ANTI-CSRF token pairs should be changed on new sessions. So once I logged out (deleted my cookie), a new ANTI-CSRF token pair was created.

I wonder if I could change this time every time.